# A custom command for printing generated pdf

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get data from database and render it in a printable form.

***models.py:***

```
class PurchaseItem(models.Model):

product = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item")
quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
paid_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want all this data to be represented in an invoice and be printable.I know many ways to do this but I think I need help from start. **VIEWS** section in particular is giving me headaches.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you want your users to interact with the app: by a command typed in a command line interface or accessed via a web page like by pressing a button? What should be the expected output to meet your requirements: pdf, printable html or a web page that automatically opens the print prompt? Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 4.x. I have tried to create views but I am not good at understanding them. By id, i want to interact with it on the admin panel of the website. It should be a viewable and printable html or pdf. Hope that helps?!